# How can I import Charts.xcodeproj using cocoapods?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, ios-charts

I'd like to use ios-charts on my iOS App written in Objective-C, and tried to fetch it from cocoapods.

My Podfile is

```
platform :ios, "9.0"
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'FMDB', '~> 2.0'
  pod 'Charts', '~> 2.1'
end
```

I could retrieve Charts, but couldn't find 'Charts.xcodeproj'.

Reading README.md, it says

> Drag the Charts.xcodeproj to your project

But I couldn't find that file.

Does anybody know how to get 'Charts.xcodeproj' using cocoapods?

Comment: Thank you marko for editing my question.
I'm sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you decide to intregrate the library with CocoaPods , put your Podfile on the same folder of your .xcodeproj project,then open a terminal ,navigate to that path and write:

```
pod install
```

After installation completes,close Xcode and open your newly created .xcworkspace file. Be careful: don't open your .xcodeproj but open .xcworkspace instead.

To use your newly imported files just do:

```
@import Charts; // put this in the class where you want to use Charts!
```

Comment: Thank you!

I just wonder that the ios-charts's README.md says
Drag the `Charts.xcodeproj` to your project 
Go to your target's settings, hit the "+" under the "Embedded Binaries" section, and select the Charts.framework 

I did what you kindly taught me and then built it, but I had an error
framework not found Pods.

How can I fix this? I'm sorry to bother you, but this is my first time to use swift-based framework using cocoapods.

Comment: These steps refers to the manual way to install the Library. If you use CocoaPods you don't have to do these steps,but instead do what I suggested. If you do both installation at the same time it won't work,choose one way to install the library

Comment: I understood!

And I succeeded to build it.

Thanks again!

Comment: metronic, thanks for your help.
I succeeded to draw the graph.

But I'm trying to add Balloon to my Objective-C app for about 5 hours, but still I can't find how to solve this.